# PySpark cumulative lag logic

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

In `PySpark Databricks`, I'm trying to recalculate column A in `dataframe` using following recursive formula:

```
A1 = A0 + A0 * B0 / 100    
A2 = A1 + A1 * B1 / 100
```

...

Initial Table

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 3740 | -15 |
| 3740 | -5 |
| 3740 | -10 |

(unlimited depth)

Result

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 3740 | -15 |
| 3179 | -5 |
| 3020.05 | -10 |

(unlimited depth)

Maybe someone has an idea?

Tried lag function, but it doesn't support recursive calculation, and I can't find a way to bypass it. Row-by-row processing takes endless amount of time because of the data amount.

Comment: you don't seem to need a recursive approach. you could just lag the columns based on a sorting column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your column B is variable, you get the list of it and use any one of the functions like below and call as udf function.

```py
def calculate_nth_term(A0, n):
    An = float(A0)
    for i in range(n):
        An *= (1 + B[i]/100)
    return An
```

or

```py
def calculate_nth_term(A0, n):
    if n==0:
        return float(A0)
    else:
        An = calculate_nth_term(A0,n-1)*(1 + B[n-1]/100)
        return An
```

Here, **B** is the list taken from the dataframe.

code:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf, row_number,lit

B = df.select("B").rdd.map(lambda x : x.B).collect()

calculate_An_udf = udf(calculate_nth_term, FloatType())

windowSpec = Window().orderBy("A")
tmp_df = df.withColumn("n", row_number().over(windowSpec)-lit(1))
tmp_df.withColumn("An",calculate_An_udf(col("A"),col("n"))).show()
```

This calculates results in recursive way.

output:

| A | B | n | An |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3740 | -15 | 0 | 3740 |
| 3740 | -5 | 1 | 3179 |
| 3740 | -10 | 2 | 3020.05 |